# BufferedReader and stream Line Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

Working with BufferedReader: I have a text file that has similar lines as listed below. 
Text File line sample:

```
ABC  DEF  EFG 1.2.3.3 MGM -Ba\
10.101.0.10
```

How can I remove the end of the line char `\` after `-Ba` and join the next line/Field to the first line to have a new line then store it in an array to print later.

What  I want to have is to able to join the 2 lines if `\` is found at end of the 1st line then assign each element of the "2 lines" (Now ONE LINE) that is separated by the delimiter " "  to Fields where I can call later to print. but I Also want to remove the unwanted characters `\` found at the end of the line.

Here is what I want to have as the new combined line to store in an array

```
Field-1 Field-2 Field-3 Field-4 Field-5 Field-6;
```

Where the first line of the new array will be equal to

```
Field-1 = ABC Field-2 = DEF Field-3 = EFG Field-4 = 1.2.3.3 Field-5 = -Ba Field-6 = 10.101.0.10;
```

the new combined line (2 in one ) will be generated if `\` char is found at the end of the first line.

what I have thus far in the Bufferedreader class

```
public class ReadFile {

    private String path;

    ReadFile(String filePath) {
        path = filePath;
    }

    public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

        int numberOfLines = readLines();
        String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
            textData[i] = textReader.readLine();

        }

        textReader.close();
        return textData;

    }
//Not sure if It's better to have while loop instead of this to reach end of file, let me know what you think?
    int readLines() throws IOException {
        FileReader f2r = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(f2r);
        String aLine;
        int numberOfLines = 0;
        while ((aLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            numberOfLines++;

        }
        bf.close();
        return numberOfLines;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would read a text file and concatenate any lines which end with a '\' with the following line.

Two important notes here, this assumes that the input is correct and that the \ character is the last character in the line (you would have to sanitize the input if this is not true), and that the last line of the file does not end with a backslash.

```
try (Bufferedreader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    StringBuilder concatenatedLine = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> formattedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

        //If this one needs to be concatenated with the next,
        if( line.charAt(line.length() -1) == '\\' ){ 
            //strip the last character from the string
            line = line.substring(0, line.length()-1); 
            //and add it to the StringBuilder
            concatenatedLine.append(line);
        }
        //If it doesn't, this is the end of this concatenated line
        else{
            concatenatedLine.append(line);
            //Add it to the formattedStrings collection.
            formattedStrings.add(concatenatedLine.toString());
            //Clear the StringBuilder
            concatenatedLine.setLength(0);
        }
    }

    //The formattedStrings arrayList contains all of the strings formatted for use.
}
```

Comment: The formattedStrings arrayList at the end contains it all, you can loop over that with a for each loop.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get it to work using a simple file, but when I used my actual log file, I get String index out of range: -1. Any-clue?

Comment: I figured out what's causing the index out of Range. It was caused by blank lines. so I added if (line.isEmpty()){line = line.trim();} before your If statement then changed your If to "else if" and it worked. Thanks again for your help on this!!!

Comment: can you comment on the  2 lines below and provide your thought process to document if you don't mind.......  StringBuilder concatenatedLine = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> formattedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: If you're trying to turn this in for school, it honestly has too many comments right now- I just added those to explain it for you. The two lines you're talking about create the data structures used below it. Look up the words concatenation and the pages for StringBuilder and ArrayList for more info

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me on this, I greatly appreciate you feedback and detailed explanation. Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you take a look at the 2nd part of my question please found here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355803/bufferedreader-to-read-lines-then-assign-the-new-formed-lines-tokens-to-variab

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the file twice. One to determine its length and another to read the lines. Use a variable size container instead so you can read the file without knowing its lenght.

You can detect if a line ends in '\' with string.chartAt(string.length-1).

Here is the code to put those two principles in action :

```
public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(); // Store read lines in a variable
                                            // size container

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String partialLine = null; // Holds a previous line ending in \ or
    // null if no such previous line
    for (;;)
    {
        String line = textReader.readLine(); // read next line
        if ( line==null )
        {   // If end of file add partial line if any and break out of loop
            if ( partialLine!=null )
                lines.add(partialLine);
            break;
        }
        boolean lineEndsInSlash =   line.length()!=0 &&
                                    line.charAt(line.length()-1)=='\\';
        String filteredLine; // Line without ending \
        if ( lineEndsInSlash )
            filteredLine = line.substring(0, line.length()-1);
        else
            filteredLine = line;
        // Add this line to previous partial line if any, removing ending \ if any
        if ( partialLine==null )
            partialLine = filteredLine;
        else
            partialLine += filteredLine;
        // If the line does not end in \ it is a completed line. Add to
        // lines and reset partialLine to null. Otherwise do nothing, next
        // iteration will keep adding to partial line
        if ( !lineEndsInSlash )
        {
            lines.add(partialLine);
            partialLine = null;
        }
    }

    textReader.close();

    return lines.toArray( new String[lines.size()] );
}
```

I've kept String[] as the return type since that might be a requirement you can't avoid. But I suggest you to change it to List if possible. It is a more suitable type.

To do so OpenFile should be changed like this :

```
public List<String> OpenFile() throws IOException {
.......
    return lines; /// Instead of: return lines.toArray( new String[lines.size()] );
}
```

And it would be used like this :

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try { 
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile("/home/user/file.txt"); 
        List<String> aryLines = file.OpenFile(); 
        for ( String s : aryLines) { 
            System.out.println(s); 
        }
    }
    catch ( IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println( "Reading failed : " + ex.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how I am calling it: try {
            ReadFile file = new ReadFile(filePath);
            System.out.println(filePath);
            String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();
            for (int i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(aryLines[i]); 

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }   how will I call it if I change it to List, can you update it to List and let me know if any thing different I need to do?

Comment: Substitute your for bucle --- for ( String s : aryLines) { System.out.println(s) } --- The rest is the same except for the type of aryLines : List aryLines = file.openFile() . List is documented at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: try {
            ReadFile file = new ReadFile(filePath);
            System.out.println(filePath);
            List aryLines = file.OpenFile();
            for ( String s : aryLines)  {
                System.out.println(aryLines(s); 

            }
it Says string cannot be converted to List

Comment: I figured out what's causing index out of range, it turns out that the method is having an issue with while spaced lines. how can we trim them down and remove the "/" from end of line?

Comment: You are right. It is an edge case. I've updated the code to consider lines of size 0. Also, to remove the ending \ add a substring without the last char instead of the whole string as also shown in my update.

Comment: I had to change public List<String> OpenFile() throws IOException { and it's working like charm. I see the blank lines are not trimed, but they are ignored. can you explain how the code is doing that. I am trying to read between the lines. so Any pointer is greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: Blank lines have a length of 0.So lineEndsInSlash will be false because the left side of the && operator is false. This will then cause line to be assigned to filteredLine; as opposed to the substring. This is important because if we take a substring ending at lenght-1 from a blank line we get an exception since lenght is zero. Then if the previous line ended in slash this blank line is added (which will cause no difference since you are adding nothing to the previous line) and the previous line will be printed because this one does not end in slash. If the previous line ...

Comment: ... did not end in slash then this blank line becomes the whole line and, since it does not en in slash, it will be printed, so you get a blank line printed plus the carriage return which is always printed with println.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to define a new `BufferedReader` with the behavior you want.  Here I've subclassed `BufferedReader` to override the behavior of `.readLine()` so that it treats lines ending with the given character as continuations.

```
public class ConcatBufferedReader extends BufferedReader {
  private final char continues;

  public ConcatBufferedReader(char continues, Reader in) {
    super(in);
    this.continues = continues;
  }

  @Override
  public String readLine() throws IOException {
    StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
    String line = super.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
      if (line.charAt(line.length()-1) == continues) {
        lines.append(line.substring(0, line.length()-1)).append(' ');
      } else {
        return lines.append(line).toString();
      }
      line = super.readLine();
    }
    // Handle end-of-file
    return lines.length() == 0 ? null : lines.toString();
  }
}
```

You can then use this just like any other `BufferedReader`, e.g.:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new ConcatBufferedReader('\\',
         Files.newBufferedReader(yourFile))) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I Print the tokens after I combined the lines? Field-1 = ABC Field-2 = DEF Field-3 = EFG Field-4 = 1.2.3.3 Field-5 = -Ba Field-6 = 10.101.0.10;

Comment: That's a separate question, but I would use a [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) to split the line on multiple whitespace (`\\s+`), then just prepend each element with the `Field-N = ` text you want.

Comment: Thanks, 2 things. 1) This is how I am getting the file path: String filePath = configFile.getAbsolutePath(); now Files.newBufferedReader(filePath))) { is giving me string cannot be converted to path i used the quote and it didn't work 2) lines.append(line.substring(0, line.length()-1).append(' '));  I am getting can't find symbol for .append(''));

Comment: It's easier if you edit your question rather than paste code in comments. But I'll try to take a look soon

Comment: Use `Paths.get()` to convert a `String` to a `Path`.  Also see the [Java tutorial on `Files` and `Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).  The append error is fixed.

Comment: How to print your Array, here is how I am calling it..... try (BufferedReader reader = new ConcatBufferedReader('\\',
         Files.newBufferedReader(p1))) {
                           for (String s : lines) {
                System.out.println(s);
            } I can't use lines for some reasons. can you please help?

Comment: Well of course you can't use `lines`; it's a variable declared inside `ConcatBufferedReader.readLine()`.  Like I said, you should use `ConcatBufferedReader` like any other `BufferedReader` (e.g. `while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)`).  The benefit of this class is it wraps up and hides the concatenation behavior so you don't have to deal with it.