# BufferedReader to read lines, then assign the new formed line's tokens to variables

Tags: java, java-8, java.util.scanner, token, bufferedreader

I have a text file that I need to modify before parsing it. 1) I need to combine lines if leading line ends with "\" and delete white spaced line. this has been done using this code

```
public List<String> OpenFile() throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            String line;
            StringBuilder concatenatedLine = new StringBuilder();
            List<String> formattedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if (line.isEmpty()) {
                    line = line.trim();

                } else if (line.charAt(line.length() - 1) == '\\') {
                   line = line.substring(0, line.length() - 1);
                   concatenatedLine.append(line);
                }  else {
                    concatenatedLine.append(line);
                    formattedStrings.add(concatenatedLine.toString());
                    concatenatedLine.setLength(0);
                }
            }
            return formattedStrings;
        }

    }
}//The formattedStrings arrayList contains all of the strings formatted for use.
```

Now My question, how can I search those lines for pattern and assign their token[i] to variables that I can call or use later.

the New combined text will look like this:

```
Field-1 Field-2 Field-3 Field-4 Field-5 Field-6 Field-7
```

Now, if the line contains "Field-6" and "Field-2" Then set the following:

```
String S =token[1] token[3]; 
String Y =token[5-7];
```

Question you might have for me, how am I deciding on which token to save to a string? I will manually search for the pattern in the text file and if the "Line contain Field-6 and Field-2 or any other required pattern. Then manually count which token I need to assign to the string. However, it will be nice if there is another way to approach this, for ex assign what's in between token[4] and token[7] to string (s) if the line has token[2] and token[6]. or another way that provides more Granule Control over what to store as string and what to ignore.

Comment: Does the text follow any predictable pattern? How are you deciding which tokens are the car types and which ones is the year? Also, the line above does not match "like Cars". It matches "like" and it matches "Cars", but not "like Cars".

Comment: I modified my question with match "like" and "cars": Regarding which token to print, I am deciding based on the token number. However, it will be nice if there is another way that gives more Granule control  in such that it allows me to reference print what's between"new" and "6" which is car type "Audi"

Comment: The question is how you are supposed to do so *generally*. I mean, how would you know what to take from the sentence "Honda Civic is one of the Cars I liked in 2013" or "Cars: Of all Chevrolet models in 2014 I like the Impala". And by the way, what would you do with "Cars: I **don't** like the Volkswagen Golf planned for 2016"?

Comment: updated the question, I hope this helps. the car example  was to give you an idea of what I am looking for. but in reality, I will need to parse the info I need manually -- determine the token that token I need to assign to the string. I hope my edits clear your inquiry. Thanks again for looking into it!!!